# 'Promise' is undefined in IE11

Tags: popup, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise, polyfills, divi

I have used this plugin to create popups in the Divi website I have built:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/popups-for-divi/

The popups were not opening in IE because of the padStart() function and I found an alternative to replace the padStart() function using this code:

<
script >

```
if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
    String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength, padString) {
        targetLength = targetLength >> 0; //truncate if number or convert non-number to 0;
        padString = String((typeof padString !== 'undefined' ? padString : ' '));
        if (this.length > targetLength) {
            return String(this);
        } else {
            targetLength = targetLength - this.length;
            if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                padString += padString.repeat(targetLength / padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
            }
            return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + String(this);
        }
    };
} <
/script>
```

Now the problem is, the popups are loading fine on Homepage but not on other pages and I am getting this error:

'Promise' is undefined

Can anyone help me get this problem resolved? This is the link to the website to check:
https://site2.stagging.tk/

Thanks

Comment: Wait, you mean someone is still coding for IE?

Comment: Not exactly @jfriend00. Though I am stuck with a client who needs this to work on IE as well. 

As he is still using IE.

Comment: Well, IE does not have native support for promises (it's really, really, really old).  You would have to also use a [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) for `Promise`.  This is a major losing battle to try to back port something to IE that you never intended for that.  Just imagine the testing involved to know that everything actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by adding these two lines of code in the Header:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/unfetch/polyfill/index.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.